Mutual exclusivity pairs using dataframe
How to check are the attributes mutually exclusive? That is, can a word have more than one non-zero entry in the
sentiment attributes?
Would like to check if each attribute is mutually exclusive of one another and to enumerate through all pairs to compare each.
N | P | U | L | S | W
0   1   ...
0   2   ...
1   0   ...
0   0   ...

N P, N U, N L, N S, N W
P U, P L, P S, P W
U L, U S, U W
L S, S W

Stumped using iloc here and if I can set my for loops to something like:
a=range(0,7)
b=range(0,7)
for i in a:
  for j in b:
    sum(df.iloc[:,i]*df.iloc[:,j]!=0)

However I know this produces an error, how to then dynamically update the index within iloc to iterate through each column?
If the sum is 0, then col 0 and 1 are mutually exclusive. Now to iterate over all columns and enumerate through nested loops.


Check all pairs.
The pair is mutually exclusive, if (df[ii] * df[jj] != 0).sum() == 0:

import pandas as pd


def get_mut_ex(D):
    df = pd.DataFrame(D)
    cols = df.columns
    res, n = [], len(cols)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            ii, jj = cols[i], cols[j]
            print(df[jj], df[ii])
            if (df[ii] * df[jj] != 0).sum() == 0:
                res += [(ii, jj)]
    return res


D = {
    'N': [0, 0, 1, 0],
    'P': [1, 2, 0, 0],
    'U': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'L': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'S': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'W': [0, 0, 0, 0]
}

print(get_mut_ex(D))



Prints
[('N', 'P'), ('N', 'U'), ('N', 'L'), ('N', 'S'), ('N', 'W'), ('P', 'U'), ('P', 'L'), ('P', 'S'), ('P', 'W'), ('U', 'L'), ('U', 'S'), ('U', 'W'), ('L', 'S'), ('L', 'W'), ('S', 'W')]
